# Post Data not decoded properly

Tags: php, oauth

I am using CURL to send the request on server to get the data.Following my php code to request get data from server.

```
<?php 
$data_string = array('grant_type'=>'authorization_code',
'orgID'=>'ORG_bbfad6',
'access_token'=>'c309792551930b835a0163835097bfc9ac4e31be',
'fromDate'=>'2016-09-21',
'toDate'=>'2016-09-21');   

//Web API URL                                                                         
$service_url='http://192.168.65.106:8080/test/range';   

$ch = curl_init($service_url);                                                                      

//request header
$headers = array( 
        //"POST "." HTTP/1.0", 
        "Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
        "Accept:application/json",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache", 
        "Connection: Keep-Alive",
        "Pragma: no-cache", 
); 

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);      

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);                                                                                                          
$curl_response = curl_exec($ch);

if ($curl_response === false)
{
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));
}

$decoded = json_decode($curl_response);

curl_close($ch);
echo 'response ok!';
print("<pre>");
var_dump($decoded);
 print("</pre>");
```

?>

On server when i print $_POST is is showing in following format

```
[{"--------------------------95901a4b56edd440\r\nContent-Disposition:_form-data;_name":"\"grant_type\"\r\n\r\nauthorization_code\r\n--------------------------95901a4b56edd440\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"orgID\"\r\n\r\nORG_bbfad6\r\n--------------------------95901a4b56edd440\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"access_token\"\r\n\r\nc309792551930b835a0163835097bfc9ac4e31be\r\n--------------------------95901a4b56edd440\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fromDate\"\r\n\r\n2016-09-21\r\n--------------------------95901a4b56edd440\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"toDate\"\r\n\r\n2016-09-21\r\n--------------------------95901a4b56edd440--\r\n","0":"\"grant_type\"\r\n\r\nauthorization_code\r\n--------------------------95901a4b56edd440\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"orgID\"\r\n\r\nORG_bbfad6\r\n--------------------------95901a4b56edd440\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"access_token\"\r\n\r\nc309792551930b835a0163835097bfc9ac4e31be\r\n--------------------------95901a4b56edd440\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fromDate\"\r\n\r\n2016-09-21\r\n--------------------------95901a4b56edd440\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"toDate\"\r\n\r\n2016-09-21\r\n--------------------------95901a4b56edd440--\r\n"}]
```

But when i used POSTMAN to check the request and response it is working fine.

Please help me where i did mistake in request.

If you need any more information please let me know.

Comment: it is unclear what the symptom of the mistake is.  what about *the following format* is not expected?  what were you expecting?  i'm just not seeing it.

Comment: I want normal $_POST array.Not encoded. I used Ouath server to check access token for it i need to use x-www-form-urlencoded. but in other business login i used normat $_POST array which is i got when i used form-data. So i need to get post values after authenticate access token to next operation.

Comment: Try removing the `Accept:application/json`. It looks like it's trying to json_encode your form.

Comment: to understand more clearly what's being given to you from the call to your web service **change** `$decoded = json_decode($curl_response);` **temporarily to** `die('<pre>'.print_r($curl_response,1));` and post the output please.

Comment: I check with that but not working. I am not understand that the same code is working in POSTMAN chrome extension. When i send request from postman it is working fine from server. but when i send request from CURL it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pasting data array if we pass data string with  x-www-form-urlencoded POST data it will solve the issue.

Thanks.